# I can't install snowalert

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I refer to the following articles for installing SnowAlert.
https://datumstudio.jp/blog/1215_snowflake_17/

I pasted the cat command as shown below and pressed the Enter key, but it doesn't run.
"First, copy and paste the cat command output during the installation into your terminal to create the snowalert-  .envs file."

Do you know the cause?

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you are meaning this section:

```
cat <<END_OF_FILE > snowalert-<account>.envs
SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT=<account>
SA_USER=snowalert
SA_ROLE=snowalert
SA_DATABASE=snowalert
SA_WAREHOUSE=snowalert
REGION=<region>.<provider>
PRIVATE_KEY=XXXXXXXXXX
PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD=<key_passphase>
END_OF_FILE
```

Which is not Windows valid commands. I don't have docker or linux on this PC, but using gitBash (MINGW64) I can run that with substitutions just fine:

```
Simeon@Simeon2 MINGW64 ~
$
```

if I paste this block

```
cat <<END_OF_FILE > snowalert-account_name.envs
SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT=account_name
SA_USER=snowalert
SA_ROLE=snowalert
SA_DATABASE=snowalert
SA_WAREHOUSE=snowalert
REGION=region.provider
PRIVATE_KEY=XXXXXXXXXX
PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD=key_passphase
END_OF_FILE
```

it is accepted:

```
Simeon@Simeon2 MINGW64 ~
$ cat <<END_OF_FILE > snowalert-account_name.envs
> SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT=account_name
> SA_USER=snowalert
> SA_ROLE=snowalert
> SA_DATABASE=snowalert
> SA_WAREHOUSE=snowalert
> REGION=region.provider
> PRIVATE_KEY=XXXXXXXXXX
> PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD=key_passphase
> END_OF_FILE

Simeon@Simeon2 MINGW64 ~
```

and if I cat that file:

```
$ cat snowalert-account_name.envs
```

I get back

```
SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT=account_name
SA_USER=snowalert
SA_ROLE=snowalert
SA_DATABASE=snowalert
SA_WAREHOUSE=snowalert
REGION=region.provider
PRIVATE_KEY=XXXXXXXXXX
PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD=key_passphase
```

so `<account>`, `<region>`, `<provider>`, and `<key_passphase>` all have to be replaced with correct values that have no `<`,`>` values in them, into a bash shell.

OR you can just open the file with any file editor and put the same valid context in.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I was able to solve it.
I am very grateful that I could never solve it by myself.